# Constraint on relationship existence (Cypher)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create a relationship similar to the following:

```
  create constraint hasSource for (i:Information)-[r:SOURCED_FROM]->(s: Source) assert r is not null
```

Essentially I want all information nodes to have (at least one) source.

Comment: What is your question?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible as per the latest version of neo4j. You can create an `existence constraint` on the `property` of a `relationship`, but you cannot create a constraint between two nodes, to have a particular relation. This sort of validation needs to be taken care of at the application level.

Here is link to the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/constraints/) related to constraints.